# C# Selenium XPath , call click function of a link text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsP00.png)

I need to click the 'Practice Form' tag highlighted in the attached image using C# Selenium here.

The url of form is https://demoqa.com/forms
and the upon clicking 'Practice Form' it will be redirected to https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form.

I need to achieve this through clicking, not by navigating.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: I tried accessing through ID , by need to achieve this through XPath , since the field is dynamic , any idea?

Comment: Always add your attempts to your question.

Comment: A screenshot of the UI is helpful in some situations but we have no idea what the HTML looks like for this page to provide you a locator to click your desired element. You need to add the relevant HTML to the question, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

This XPATH should perfectly work:

```
//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//ancestor::li[@class='btn btn-light ']
```

Short explanation:

1. You find span containing specified text
2. You go to ancestor to get button's `xpath`.

You need to find it with selenium and use Selenium's `click()`
This is one of xpaths you can use.
Another option is just going a level up:

```
//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]/..
```

I like both.
Option 3:

```
//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//parent::li[contains(@class,'btn btn-light')]
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful, consider accepting/voting

Comment: Ancestor doesn't work for me, but this does:  `//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//parent::li[@id='item-0']`.  Maybe it just something on my end

Comment: This doesn't work :

Could not find element by: By.XPath: /span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//ancestor::li[@class='btn btn-light ']'

Comment: It's strange. I tested it. Your option is good as well

Comment: `//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//ancestor::li[@class='btn btn-light ']` Also try the second option.

Comment: Yes both are not working , since the practice form url should be this https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form upon manually clicking Practice , 
But if I do it with your way , it is redirecting me to https://demoqa.com/forms/automation-practice-form

Comment: Clarify, do you need locator for https://demoqa.com/forms  or for demoqa.com/forms/automation-practice-form ?

Comment: The url of forms is https://demoqa.com/forms 
Then it will show a 'Practice Form Link' , I need to click that link , which will take me to pracice form page , whose link would be 'https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form'

Comment: Did you try xpath suggested by @JD2775 ?

Comment: Yes I did , it is taking me to 'demoqa.com/forms/automation-practice-form'
But if I manually click , it takes me to 'demoqa.com/automation-practice-form'

And this is the problem.

Comment: Check third option. If I manually click, I'm redirected to https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

Comment: This is how I am trying :

 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//parent::li[contains(@class,'btn btn-light')]")]
        public IWebElement PracticeBtn { get; set; }





Method :

public PracticeForms ClickToToPracticeForms()
        {
            PracticeBtn.Click();
           // this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(practiceFormsUrl);
            return new PracticeForms(driver);
        }

Comment: Option 3 , is taking me to wrong url : 'https://demoqa.com/forms/automation-practice-form'

Comment: It should if you click on the area from your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why yours isn't working, but this works fine for me:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.demoqa.com/forms");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'Practice Form')]//parent::li[@id='item-0']")).Click();
```

It takes me to:

```
https://www.demoqa.com/automation-practice-form
```

With the `Student Registration` form shown in the middle

BTW in your original comments you said you had to use XPath for this because that field is "dynamic".  It is not dynamic.  The element has more than one `ID: item-0`, maybe that is what you meant by couldn't use `ID`.  But the element itself is not "dynamic"

Comment: If this won't help, I'll vote for closing the question because it lacks details...

Answer (score 0):

This simple XPath works for me

```
//span[text()='Practice Form']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below xpath

```
//li[@class[contains(.,'btn-light')]][contains(.,'Practice Form')]
```